# Cassandra - reading with consistency level ONE

Tags: cassandra

How is reading with CL ONE implemented by Cassandra?

Does coordinator query all replicas and waits for the first to answer?

According to documentation, coordinator should query one single closest replica. What happens if timeout occurs during this query - does it try another replica, or it returns error to client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does coordinator query all replicas and waits for the first to answer?

As you mentioned, it queries the closest node, as determined by the snitch.

> What happens if timeout occurs during this query

There is additional documentation on the [Dynamic Snitch](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/cluster_architecture/replication#dynamicsnitch), which states that:

> By default, all snitches also use a dynamic snitch layer that monitors
>   read latency and, when possible, routes requests away from
>   poorly-performing nodes.

By that definition, if the node chosen by the snitch should fail, the snitch should route the transaction to the [next] closest node.

Note that as of 2.0.2, Cassandra has a feature called [Rapid Read Protection](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/rapid-read-protection-in-cassandra-2-0-2), which:

> [A]llows Cassandra to tolerate node failure without dropping a single request

Comment: Are you sure about "reroute"? I've checked Cassandra 1.6 code and it seams, that in case of node failure, the client will receive error - at least in case when read repair does not occur. Call ReadCallback#filterEndpoints(...) removes all endpoints except closest one and fetchRows(...) awaits response from this single node, this is all - I could not find any retry-functionality.

Comment: You make a good point about not finding any retry logic in the code.  Cassandra's ring-based design suggests that it could lose a node and still serve reads, depending on the configured replication factor.  But since you are asking about a node failure (closest) that happens exactly during a transaction, after the node has been selected by the snitch, I suppose it is possible that a failure could occur.